# URL tracking with the presence of GET parameters

Tags: python, django

I send a request to the site with GET parameters

```
response = requests.get(f'http://localhost/botcontact&phonenumber={phonenumber}&user_id={user_id}')
```

Tracking in urls.py

```
path('botcontact/', views.botcontact)
```

I get the error `Not Found: / botcontact&phonenumber=+79162321578&user_id=228695396` How to make GET parameters not taken into account in urls.py and it could be tracked via `path ('botcontact/', views.botcontact)`? In this case, GET parameters must be obtained in the function

Comment: It should be : `requests.get(f'http://localhost/botcontact/?phonenumber={phonenumber}&user_id={user_id}')`. GET params should start with **`?`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request statement is invalid; it should start with `?`

```py
response = requests.get(f'http://localhost/botcontact?phonenumber={phonenumber}&user_id={user_id}')
```